# why remained unable to show reset image

Tags: android, image, pinchzoom

I am developing an app of wallpapers. When I have zoomed an image and clicked the <kbd>Next</kbd> button to see the next image,  the next image is shown at the zoom level remaining from previous image.

You can seen the images below and also my code.

Here is the first image in normal state.[image: image in normal state]
When I zoomed the image.

[image]
When I click the next button to change image then image seen zoomed.

[image]
Image should seen like this without zoomed.

[image]

Here is xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:gravity="fill"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:weightSum="100" > 
 <com.example.imagezoom.TouchImageView 
        android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="100" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:background="#66FFFFFF"
        android:maxHeight="91dip"
        android:maxWidth="47dip"
        android:src="@drawable/a1" />
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
  <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bprev" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back" > 
       </Button> 
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/bnext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Next" >
       </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity.

```
 public class Main extends Activity { 
   private ImageView hImageViewPic;
   private Button iButton, gButton;
   private int currentImage = 0; 
 int[] images = { R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, R.drawable.r3, R.drawable.r4, R.drawable.r5, R.drawable.r6, R.drawable.r7, R.drawable.r8, R.drawable.r9, R.drawable.r10 };
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
    hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);
      iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext); 
      gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bprev);
   //Just set one Click listener for the image 
      iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener); 
      gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener);
   } 
     View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
       public void onClick(View v) {
     //Increase Counter to move to next Image 
      currentImage++;
      currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
     hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
      } 
    };
     View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
       public void onClick(View v) { 
    //Increase Counter to move to next Image 
      currentImage--; 
      currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
    hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]); 
   }
    };
   }
```

TouchImageView.

```
  public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
   Matrix matrix;
    // We can be in one of three states 
   static int NONE=0; 
   static int DRAG=1;
   static int ZOOM=2;
   int mode=NONE;
    // Remember some things for zooming
   PointF last = new PointF (); 
   PointF last = new PointF ();
   float minScale = 1f; 
   float maxScale = 2f; 
   float[] m;
   int viewWidth, viewHeight; 
   static int CLICK = 3;
   float saveScale = 1f;
   protected float origWidth, origHeight; 
   int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight; 
   ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
   Context context;

  public TouchImageView (Context context) {
   super (context);
   sharedConstructing ( context );
  } 
  public TouchImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
  super ( context, attrs ); 
  sharedConstructing ( context );
  }
  public void resetView () { 
  // we can be in one of three states 
  NONE = 0; 
  DRAG = 1; 
  ZOOM = 2;
  mode = NONE; 
   last = new PointF ( ); 
   start= new PointF ( );
   minScale = 1f;
   maxScale = 2f;
   CLICK =3;
   saveScale = 1f;
   matrix = new Matrix ();
   m = new float [ 9 ]; 
   setImageMatrix ( matrix ); 
   setScaleType ( ScaleType.MATRIX ); 
  } 
   private void sharedConstructing ( Context context ) { 
    Super.setClickable (true); 
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector ( context, new ScaleListener ());
    matrix = new Matrix (); 
    m = new float [ 9 ];
    setImageMatrix ( matrix ); 
    setScaleType ( ScaleType.MATRIX );
    setOnTouchListener ( new OnTouchListener ( ) {
  @Override 
    public boolean OnTouch (View v, MotionEvent event ) {
      mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent ( event );
      PointF curr = new PointF ( event.getX ( ), event.getY ( ) );
      switch ( event.getAction ( ) ) { 
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
      last.set ( curr);
      start.set ( last ); 
      mode = DRAG;
     break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        if ( mode = = DRAG ) { 
    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
    float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans (deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale ); 
    float FixTransY = getFixDragTrans (deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale );
    matrix.postTranslate (fixTransX, fixTransY);
    fixTrans (); 
    last.set ( curr.x, curr.y ); 
   } 
 break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : 
   mode = NONE;
   int xDiff = ( int ) Math.abs ( curr.x - start.x ); 
   int yDiff = ( int ) Math.abs ( curr.y - start.y ); 
   if ( xDiff < CLICK & & yDiff < CLICK ) performClick ( ); 
 break; 
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP :
      mode = NONE; 
     break;
     } 
   setImageMatrix ( matrix );
    invalidate ( ); 
    return true; 
  // indicate event was handled 
  }
  });
 }
   public void setMaxZoom ( float x ) { 
    maxScale = x;
    } 
   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
  @Override
   public boolean onScaleBegin ( ScaleGestureDetector detector ) { 
     mode = ZOOM; 
     return true; 
    } 
  @Override
   public boolean onScale ( ScaleGestureDetector detector ) { 
    float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor ( );
    float origScale = saveScale;
    saveScale * = mScaleFactor;
    if ( saveScale > maxScale ) { 
    saveScale = maxScale;
    mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
   } else if ( saveScale < minScale ) { 
    saveScale = minScale;
    mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
     } 
  if ( origWidth * saveScale < = viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale < = viewHeight) matrix.postScale ( mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2 );
  else matrix.postScale ( mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY ( ) ); 
  fixTrans (); 
  return true;
     }
   }
   void FixTrans () { 
    matrix.getValues ( m );
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X ]; 
    float transY = m [ Matrix.MTRANS_Y ]; 
    float fixTransX = getFixTrans (transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale ); 
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans (transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale ); 
    if ( FixTransX! = 0 || fixTransY! = 0) matrix.postTranslate ( fixTransX, fixTransY);
    } 
   float getFixTrans (float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize){ 
   float minTrans, maxTrans;
   if ( contentSize <= viewSize) { 
     minTrans = 0; 
     maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
     } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
        } 
 if (trans < minTrans) return -trans + minTrans;
 if (trans > maxTrans) return - trans + maxTrans;
 return 0;
 }
  float getFixTrans (float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
   if ( contentSize <= viewSize) { 
   return 0; 
   }
   return delta; 
    }
   @Override
     protected void onMeasure ( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ) { 
      super.onMeasure ( widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );
      viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize ( widthMeasureSpec ); 
     viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize ( heightMeasureSpec );
    // Rescaled image on rotation 
  if ( oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
   return; 
  oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight; 
  oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;
  if ( saveScale == 1) {
  // Fit to screen 
   float scale; 
   Drawable drawable = getDrawable ();
   if ( drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth () == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight () == 0) 
   return;
   int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth ();
   int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight ();
   Log.d ("bmSize", "bmWidth:" + bmWidth + " bmHeight:" + bmHeight); 
   float scaleX = ( float ) viewWidth / ( float ) bmWidth;
   float scaleY = ( float ) bmHeight / ( float ) bmHeight; 
   scale = Math.min ( scaleX, scaleY ); 
   matrix.setScale ( scale, scale );
    // Center the image
   float redundantYSpace = ( float ) viewHeight - ( scale * ( float ) bmHeight );
   float redundantXSpace = ( float ) viewWidth - ( scale * ( float ) bmWidth ); 
   origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace; 
   origHeight = viewHeight -2 * redundantYSpace; 
   setImageMatrix ( matrix );
  }
   fixTrans (); 
  } 
 }
```

Please help. What I have to do to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `resetview()` in your `ButtonChangeImageListener`.

Basically, you need to call `resetView()` in your `next or prev` `onClick()`

EDIT:
1. You might have to .. in your `MainActivity`, you have `hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);` This should be `hImageViewPic = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);`

1. (obligatory)
   in `TouchView.java`, in `iButtonChangeImageListener` and `gButtonChangeImageListener`, you have to add the line `hImageViewPic.resetView()`.

Comment: Thanx bro. Can you plz tell me how can I call resetview. I am new to android and don't know much about this.

Comment: Sir when I add hImageViewPic.resetView ().then resetview is showing error.

Comment: plz post error log = stack trace .. and did you typecast the `imageview` as `TouchImageView`?

Comment: Aftab bro. Thanx a lot. You have solved my problem. Again thanx.